# Catching PL/SQL errors in JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql, oracle11g

I'm creating a Java application which connects to an oracle database via JDBC and is able to execute scripts on in. Somewhat like toad.
The reason I am creating this is because we can't use Toad or SQLplus in our closed working space.

Everything is working great until I come to procedures,functions,triggers,packages,... (the most important items to say).

I am able to send them trough the JDBC driver, but it always says it is succesfull, even when it wasn't.
In SQLplus you get a message saying '.... created with compilation errors', so in fact it isn't a real error either. but then you are able to show the errors.

Is there a way to acces those errors you get with `show errors` via JDBC? So I atleast now is an error occured.

Comment: Have you checked the [`Statement.getWarnings()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getWarnings()) and [`Connection.getWarnings()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#getWarnings()) for warnings?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I just did and I now get: 'Warning: execution completed with warning' but I still don't get the actual error.

Comment: Follow the instructions in the Javadoc: you need to 'walk' over the exceptions using [SQLException.getNextException()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html#getNextException()) or using the [iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html#iterator())

Comment: What about using one of the open source JDBC based SQL tools instead of re-inventing the wheel? If the "closed working space" is because of concerns regarding the tool, you could check the source code of them to make sure everything complies with your environment

Comment: That was a great comment and very helpful to me. I found that Flyway had solved that same problem, and was able to implement a similar solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use system view `ALL_ERRORS`

Example:

```
select * 
from ALL_ERRORS  
where owner = 'your_schema' 
and name = 'your_package_name' 
and type = 'PACKAGE BODY' 
order by sequence
```

Comment: this did the trick thank you! you don't happen to know how I can find the last altered object?

Comment: @Sonaryr - Probably, `select * from all_objects where owner = 'your_schema' AND object_type in ('PACKAGE', 'PACKAGE BODY') order by last_ddl_time desc`